# Does anyone have a nice awk for svn log output?

Tags: svn, awk, grep

I want to search the commit messages for a string, it's easy to pipe svn log to a grep, but because the message and the rev are on separate lines, it's a little more complicated.

i.e.

svn log ./ | searchSvnMessages.awk artf29999

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r9303 | myuser | 2011-02-22 15:13:47 -0800 (Tue, 22 Feb 2011) | 1 line

artf29999: Adjusting Skin
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r9302 | myuser | 2011-02-22 14:11:06 -0800 (Tue, 22 Feb 2011) | 1 line

artf29999: Adding skinning.
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r800 | myuser | 2011-02-22 09:44:36 -0800 (Tue, 22 Feb 2011) | 1 line

artf29999: Adding functionality.
```

I was hoping that someone else had done the dirty work that I could piggyback on?

Comment: if you consider an answer the best answer for your question, click the check next to it to mark it as the accepted answer. Good for your own reputation and other people's

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you only need to search the first line of each log entry and you are using GNU grep, you can do `svn log . | grep -B2 artf29999`.

Comment: +1 The context flags (-A(fter), -B(efore), and -C(ontext)) for grep can be very helpful in places that would otherwise require scripts.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `svn log ... --xml` to get xml output, which might be easier to parse. Alternatively you can use various script bindings to get richer objects instead of parsing.

Comment: +1, If you're familiar with Perl, `svn log --xml` along with the XML::Simple module make it pretty easy to parse through svn logs.  That's what I've done on a few projects.